# Is there a way to put together or merge lists dataframe together to create a dataframe based on their index?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe, multidimensional-array

DF1 =[

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

]

DF2 = [ NY, FL ]

in this case DF1 and DF2 have two indexes.

The result I am looking for is the following

Main_DF =

[

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | NY |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | NY |

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | FL |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | FL |

]

I tried to use pd.concat, assign and insert
none give me the way I'm looking for the result to be

Comment: Are `DF1` and `DF2` lists or dataframes?  You call them lists of dataframes, use `[]` list notation, then use variable names that normally mean `dataframe`.

Answer (score 0):

Lists hold references to dataframes.  So, you can amend the dataframes and not need to amend the list at all.

So, I'd do something like...

```
for df, val in zip(DF1, DF2):
  df['Column C'] = val
```

Using `zip` allows you to iterate though the two lists in sync with each other;

- 1st element of `DF1` goes in to `df`, and 1st element of `DF2` goes into `val`
- 2nd element of `DF1` goes in to `df`, and 2nd element of `DF2` goes into `val`
- and so on